# Can custom tokencolors be added during vscode extension development?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension for text highlighting. The colors that come with textmate can no longer meet my needs, so I want to add some colors artificially. I have tried many solutions, but did not meet my demands. (The current solution is to define a new color theme)

I defined a new color theme to meet my demands. But it needs to change the default theme,and other highlighting extensions will not work. So i want to customize some tokencolors in extension witout changing the current theme. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot